# Python validating and requireng number input from user

Tags: validation, python-3.x, error-handling

Hello all I am fairly new to python and am trying to learn to be an efficient coder.  Attached is some code that validates user input is a number >= 0.  I am hoping the experts here can tell me if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks

```
budget = input("Please enter your budget for the month: ")
while type(budget) == str or budget < 0:
   try:
       budget = float(budget)
       while budget < 0:
           budget = input("Error, Please enter a positive number for the budget: ")
           try:
               budget = float(budget)
           except ValueError:
               break
   except ValueError:
       budget = input("Error, text is not valid - Please enter a number for the budget: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. It uses a lesser-known feature of the `try/except` statement, which is the `else` clause. In addition, I also separated your errors from your input to make it simpler.

```
budget = ""
while type(budget) == str or budget < 0:
    budget = input("Please enter your budget for the month: ")
    try:
        budget = float(budget)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: text is not valid")
    else:
        if budget >= 0: break
        else: print("Error: number must be positive")
```

If you wanted to get *really* fancy, you could import `sys` and make the `print` statements for each error also include the option `file=sys.stderr`, which would effectively make the output red. However, I'm not really sure if that's a "safe" technique.

Comment: I like that, its much easier to understand.  Thank you so much for your time